# python: whtat is the right way to remove element from list

Tags: python

google no found...
I want two solutions:

```
1) How to remove an element in a for..in.. loop for a list?
2) How to remove all the elements in the list?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is almost never what you want to do. Use a list comprehension to filter out the items you don't want.
2. `del L[:]`

Answer (score -1):

```
1) filter()
2) list = []
```

Comment: 1) is ugly in most cases but not worth a downvote. 2) is downright wrong. It just creates a new list and assigns that to `list` (ugh) without actually deleting any of the elements in the list.

Comment: Besides, list comprehensions should be preferred to filter()